# Cheap talk vs gossip

Tags: synonyms

Are *cheap talk* and *gossip* close synonyms or are there instances where one cannot be used to substitute the other?

Comment: I often hear "talk is cheap", but the only time I hear "cheap talk" is in reference to [game theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheap_talk).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a usage *(cheap talk = gossip)* which I think has little or no currency, and which OP hasn't supported with references.

Comment: Is cheap talk a cell phone marketing phrase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Cheap talk* and *gossip* are not close synonyms. *Gossip* is idle talk about the activities and foibles of others.  It consists of specific anecdotes used as a kind of social currency.  According to [Human Universals by Donald Brown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Universals) all human cultures engage in gossip.

*Cheap talk* derives from the expression *talk is cheap* and its corollary *actions speak louder than words*  It is a criticism that carries the implication that the speech act stands in the place of something such as action, original thought, true wisdom or spending money.

[Source](http://books.google.com/books?id=F0wCAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA337&dq=%22cheap+talk%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VCxNU-A7i82xBJGZgcgG&ved=0CEoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22cheap%20talk%22&f=false)

> ...he talked much of the imperfections and errors...without pointing out a single one of these for correction. The writer has heard this so often repeated, that the subject, and this manner of presenting it, has become somewhat stale, and he somewhat sick of it; and in his disgust at this new exhibition of an old offence, did say, this appeared to him like "very cheap talk."

The essential quality of *cheap talk* is included here "talked much of imperfections...without pointing out a single one of these for correction."   In this passage, the subject of conversation is a reference book.  Gossip applies to human foibles and the question of correcting them does not come up at all.

A politician giving a campaign speech could easily be accused of *cheap talk* for most of its content but probably not of *gossip* unless his speech contained details about his opponent's private life.